# Git URL point to submodules

Tags: java, git, selenium-webdriver

I have a parent project called AutomationRoot and it has submodules called butv3 and others submodules.

sparse checkout??

How to git url point to submodules so it can build directly from there? The reason for this is I have teamcity build server and i need to build from the submodule.

Comment: You don't get to make that call.  You cannot survive on SO unless you learn to ignore downvotes.  Your question is unclear.  Your submodules will be included with the parent project. That's how it works.  If you want a submodule separately, then clone the submodule by its own URL.

Comment: Hi, can you please try to reword the question?  For example, GitHub offers a shallow clone option, which may help fetching submodules faster, but the question is not clear (at least to me and a few others) exactly what's being asked.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of what you want to do could be just pulling `git` sub modules:

```bash
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

And then, in order to build sub module's code, you can just cd to that path and build it. Or if it is defined in the submodule's maven pom for example as of what parent is, then building from the parent folder should work as well:

module's pom:

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.....</groupId>
        <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
        <version>your-version</version>
    </parent>
```

Parent's pom:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.....</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>your-version</version>
...
```

If you want to pull and build only that module, you can, again, cd to the module's path, `git pull` and build it.